# How can a function in popupPanel.js of RichFaces 4.1.0 be overridden?

Tags: javascript, richfaces

I am having a problem with RichFaces popup panel. I need to set focus on the first input element in the popup as soon as it is opened. The user must then be able to traverse through all input elements in popup using keyboard. Currently I am using RichFaces 4.1.0.

After going through different forums I came to know that this is a bug in RichFaces 4.1.0 which has been fixed in RichFaces 4.2.3 release. This bug has been resolved by the Jboss community by making changes in function *processAllFocusElements* of *popupPanel.js* file.

I cannot migrate to RichFaces 4.2.3 as of now. So how can I override the default behavior of 
function *processAllFocusElements* so that it works correctly for me with RichFaces 4.1.0 itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to patch the RichFaces jar file and replace the popupPanel.js with the file from 4.2.3.

Probably an easier way: put 4.2.3 `popupPanel.js` file (delete the parts you don't need from it) to your project folder and load it the way you load your custom javascripts (somewhere in template I guess using `h:outputScript`).
Basically 4.1.0 `popupPanel.js` will still execute, but then your 4.2.3 version will execute and override the results.

Simple override of single method could look like this:

```
jQuery.extend(RichFaces.ui.PopupPanel.prototype, {
    processAllFocusElements: function(root, callback) {
        ....
    }
}
```